# How helpful is memorizing Clojure.core

Tags: clojure

I've used Clojure for about 2 years now (having used scheme/lisp before that).

I'm getting to the point where I feel like I'm not learning more clojure "by osmosis" and am considering using a conscious effort to memorize the function names in Clojure.core

### Question:

Has anyone else done this? If so, has it been a significant productivity boost?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that just having a function memorized is not enough to spot the need to use it when it is needed. It is better to learn in context - for example by solving the 4clojure problems and then looking at solutions by users with high scores. Once you have a function in context, then you can memorize it.